# OrderBy IndexOf a string with negatives at the bottom

Tags: linq, sorting, sql-order-by, indexof

I have a line in my code that is sorting a bunch of strings. The items being sorted are the result of a database query that brings back a bunch of titles where the search phrase is in the title column and the keywords column. I want to sort them by the first occurance of the search phrase but when the search phrase isn't in the title, they have an index of -1 and they get put at the top. I would like to have the results that don't have the search phrase in the title at the bottom.

```
q = "orange";
IQueryable.OrderBy(a => a.title.IndexOf(q));
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `-1` is being interpreted as a lower number and hence they get pushed to the front of the result.  Instead change `-1` (aka not found) into the greatest possible number and push the elements to the back

```
q = "orange";
IQueryable.OrderBy(a => {
  var index = a.title.IndexOf(q);
  return index < 0 ? Int32.MaxValue : index; });
```

Comment: Your first `:` should be a `?` instead. And it's `MaxValue` not just `Max`. Otherwise, this is good.

Comment: @Yuck doh, need more coffee :)